# Rendering Static Files With Swig

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I'm trying to develop a Blog with NodeJS. I found a nice [HTML blog theme](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog/), and put all files to **views** folder. This is the content of *app.js*

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate');

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
// I'm using Express 3, not 4.
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render('index', {menu_items:[{"link":"#","text":"TXT"},{"link":"#","text":"TXT"}]});
});


app.listen(3000);
```

This code is rendering *index.html* and also rendering **menu_items** in index.html . But it's not rendering static files like css and js.

[image]

To render them I'm commenting out **app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));** line. This time it's rendering static files but not rendering **menu_items** variable in index.html . 
[image]

You can see all files in [this repository](https://github.com/erayalakese/Blog/tree/62f584890cb5b29556eebb8123ec88d0bce2b555). Can you tell me what's I'm missing?

** UPDATE 1 **
I've added these lines instead of that commented line

```
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/views/css'));
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/views/img'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/views/js'));
```

But I'm not sure if it's correct way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you put the route string as `'/', the pattern matches all url requests. And the handlers registered after '/' gets ignored. So, You need to add the lines first,

```
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/views/css'));
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/views/img'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/views/js'));
```

and then add this router at the end,

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
res.render('index', {menu_items:[{"link":"#","text":"TXT"},{"link":"#","text":"TXT"}]});
```

});

Comment: I actually put HTML files and other statics (like css, img and js) to seperate folder and just use `app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/statics'));` but this is also an acceptable answer. Thank you.